# Why is a whole number not the same when rounded in a custom function?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following custom function that rounds a number to a user-specified accuracy.
It is based on the general formula:

```
ROUND(Value/ Accuracy,0)*Accuracy
```

There are times where Number/Accuracy is exactly a multiple of 0.5, and Excel does not do the common rounding rule (ODD number - Round up, EVEN number - Round down), so I made a custom function.

```
Function CheckTemp(val As Range, NumAccuracy As Range) As Double
    Dim Temp As Double
    Temp= Abs(val) / NumAccuracy

    CheckTemp = (Temp / 0.5) - WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Temp / 0.5 , 0)

End Function
```

If CheckTemp = 0, then 'val' falls under this case where depending on the number, I want to specifically round down or up. If it is false, then the general Round() command is used.

I do have a weird case when Accuracy = 0.1 and any 'val' that meets the requirement:

#.X5000000...,
where: 'X' is an ODD number, or zero (i.e. 0,1,3,5,7,9).

Depending on the whole number, the function does not work.

Example:

```
val = - 5 361 202.55
NumAccuracy = 0.1

Temp = 53 612 025.5
Temp / 0.5 = 107 224 051.
WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Temp / 0.5,0) = 107 224 051.

CheckTemp = -1.49012E-08
```

If I break this check into two separate functions, one to output (Temp/0.5) and WF.RoundDown(Temp / 0.5) to the Excel worksheet, and then subtract the two in the worksheet I get EXACTLY 0.
However with VBA coding, an error comes into play and results in a non-zero answer (even more worrisome a NEGATIVE value, which should be impossible when Temp is always positive, and RoundDown('x','y') will always result in a smaller number than 'x').

'val' can be a very large number with many decimal places, so I am trying to keep the 'Double' parameter if possible.
I tried 'Single' variable type and it seems to remove the error with CheckTemp(), but I am worried an end-user may use a number that exceeds the 'Single' variable limit.

Comment: Most likely floating-point error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not wrong, but native rounding in VBA is severely limited.

So, use a proper rounding function like *RoundMid* as found in my project [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round). It uses Decimal if possible to avoid such errors.

Example:

```vb
Value = 5361202.55
NumAccuracy = 0.1
RoundedValue = RoundMid(Value / NumAccuracy, 0) * Numaccuracy

RoundedValue -> 5361202.6
```